# Plot datetime occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I want to visualize occurrences (using pandas, matplotlib or seaborn) of every record in my two DataFrame's on date and time axis.
I got DataFrame like this:

```
df1
    Timestamp-start    datetime64[ns]

    0      2020-09-15 19:36:05
    1      2020-09-17 03:18:32
    2      2020-09-17 21:37:48
    3      2020-09-19 00:16:55
    4      2020-09-19 00:19:10
                   ...        
    201   2021-03-12 08:57:30
    202   2021-03-12 09:40:02
    203   2021-03-12 09:40:38
    204   2021-03-12 09:41:40
    205   2021-03-12 09:56:29
```

- 

```
df2
        Timestamp-start    datetime64[ns]
    
        0      2020-09-15 11:51:12
        1      2020-09-15 03:20:34
        2      2020-09-15 02:24:51
        3      2020-09-17 01:21:24
        4      2020-09-17 00:12:31
                       ...        
        201   2021-03-11 09:12:39
        202   2021-03-11 09:59:42
        203   2021-03-11 10:47:19
        204   2021-03-12 09:12:17
        205   2021-03-12 09:50:50
```

My example expected visualization for 6 rows in df:
[image]

Black vertical lines symbolize single occurrences in df1, red lines symbolize occurrences in df2.

This seems to be easy but it is so hard for me to find something similar to my expected visualization.

Comment: What will the graph look like if df1 and df2 have the same day?

Comment: Did you try eventplot?

Comment: Data will have also time, there won't be duplicated records. In the visual i put only date, but the vertical lines can be placed somewhere between two dates on x axis depending on time.
@JodyKlymak - I will try this, I didn't found that when I did research for my problem.